# jQuery Fancybox showing up tiny

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am totally baffled.  I have reduced this to the simplest possible case and run it through [W3c's validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.ericaspindler.com/private/) and I still get this tiny Fancybox window.  I've used Fancybox many many times.  Looks like this:

[image]

Page is here:  http://www.ericaspindler.com/private/

Code has had all other JS and CSS stripped out in an effort to locate interference.

The entire document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Erica Spindler | Author</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fancybox_new/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../js/fancybox_new/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" media="screen" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){     
    $("#infolink").fancybox({});
     $("#infolink").click();
  });

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="fancy" style="display:none;">
<div style="width:500px; height:500px">
<img src="../g/video_Faulkner_Society_300.jpg" width="300" height="243" alt="" />
</div></div>
<a id="infolink" href="#fancy" class="infolink" style="display:none"></a>

</body>
</html>
```

The original HTML content of the #fancy div was reduced to this one image in an effort to clarify.

Also removed the parameters I was initializing with:

```
  $(".infolink").fancybox({
    'scrolling'     : 'no',
    'titleShow'     : false,
    'overlayOpacity' : '0.7'
  });
```

Can anyone tell me my error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `display: none` should be set on the *parent* div of the one you want to act as a box. See  [#4 (inline content) in the documentation](http://fancybox.net/howto).

So move the `id="fancy"` to the child div like this:

```
<div style="display:none;">
  <div style="width:500px; height:500px" id="fancy">
```

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/iqudir/3/edit#html,live)** is the example.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this will help but your jQuery isn't written well what.

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
  $("#infolink").fancybox();
});
```

let me know if this helps at all, if not I'll keep looking into it.